# Mapping java class To JSON By Using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I want to convert the following bean class to JSON object by using Jackson library

```
public class Student {
String name ;
int id ;
List<Address> address;
}
```

I want following json

```
{
  "Name" : "sys1",
  "Id" : 1,
  "address" : [some address]
}
```

Can anyone help me how to achieve this ?.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JavaToJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            List<Address> addrList = new ArrayList<>();
            Address addr = new Address();
            addr.setArea("ABC");
            addr.setCity("XYZ");
            addrList.add(addr);

            Student std = new Student();
            std.setName("Rahul");
            std.setId(1);
            std.setAddress(addrList);

            String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(std);
            System.out.println(json);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


class Student {
    String name;
    int id;
    List<Address> address;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public List<Address> getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(List<Address> address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}

class Address {
    String area;
    String city;
    public String getArea() {
        return this.area;
    }
    public void setArea(String area) {
        this.area = area;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return this.area;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```